# Can i pass information through the URL when i am using jQuery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, hash

I have a mobile application that opens an in-app browser that uses the URL to pass information to my server , like the deviceID.

For example the browser will open the web-page (**jquery Mobile**) : `www.myserver.com/doWork.html#deviceID`

On the server part using JavaScript inside the doWork.html file, I get the deviceID like this:

```
var userId = window.location.hash.substring(1);
```

Is it ok that i pass information using the `hash #` ? In jquery mobile the hash # is used to change between pages when someone uses the `Multi-Page template structure` . So i am afraid that maybe i should use something else , like a question mark `(?)` ?

Or its perfectly fine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NO. Stop using # for your data transfers.** Let jQM do its thing. Don't disturb it. Use Query strings( adding ? in url). **My advice is to stop using query strings (? tags) and # tags to send data to the next page**. Handle it using `localStorage`. Its more secure compared to Query strings because the user wont see the URL change, so your sensitive data is hidden, at least to a little extent. `localStorage` is HTML5's API which is like a temporary storage set aside per domain. This data will persist until data is cleared in cache. Assuming you have an anchor tag which goes to dowork.html,

```
<a href="doWork.html" data-role="button">Go to Do work</a>
```

Add an attribute for device ID in the tag itself, like this :

```
<a href="doWork.html" data-deviceid="10" data-role="button">Go to Do work</a>
```

You'd be doing this dynamically you might also use it the same way. You get the gist right?

A click event for this would look like this :

```
$(document).on("click", "a", function(e) //use a class or ID for this instead of just "a"
  //prevent default
  e.preventDefault();
  //get device id from tag attribute
  var deviceId = $(this).data("deviceid");
  //set it in localStorage 
  localStorage["dId"] = deviceId;
  //redirect 
  $.mobile.changePage(this.href);
});
```

Then, in the other page's `pageinit` (or any event), get the device id from storage and send the ajax call to the server.

```
//assuming #dowork is the id of a div with data-role="page"
$(document).on("pageinit", "#dowork", function() { 
  //get from storage
  var deviceId = localStorage["dId"];
  //make ajax call or server call with deviceId here
});
```

But, if you still want to use URL for this, [look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18062971/there-must-be-an-easier-way/18066775#18066775). I've given a decent enough answer over there.

Answer (score 1):

To pass variables to the server you should avoid using the # symbol because regardless of the framework you are using this symbol is used for other purposes, to pass info to the server in a GET request you should use the ? symbol, something like this should do it:  www.myserver.com/doWork.html?deviceID=1233455

Comment: so you recommend exactly what i am doing just change the # symbol that i am attaching with the ? and it will work? The command is the same? window.location.hash.substring(1) ?

Comment: No, the command will need to change to this location.search.substring(1)