# There must be an easier way

Tags: ajax, json, jquery-mobile, optimization

I am trying to create an JQM app and are doing so by getting a lot of data from database. When I click on a link from a ajax/json generated calendar list I should then be able to get the info for that event by calling the server and get the data. As it is now I do this in 2 steps like this.

My ajax generated event list:

```
$.each(groupcalendar, function (i, val) {
    output += '<li><a href="#" data-id="' + val.mid + '" id="gotoMatch"><h2>' + val.matchformname + '</h2><p><strong>' + val.matchday + '</strong></p><p>' + val.coursename + '</p><p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>' + val.matchtime + '</strong></p></a></li>';
});
```

When I click on one of the links I want to goto a page called prematchdata.html and get the data fro that specific event. I do so by first calling the click and get the eventid from data-id like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#gotoMatch', function () {

    var matchid = $(this).attr("data-id");

    $.get("http://mypage.com/json/getmatchinfo.php?matchid="+matchid, function(data) {

        localStorage["matchinfo"] = JSON.stringify(data);

        $.mobile.changePage( "prematchdata.html", { transition: "slide", changeHash: true} );

    }, "json");

});
```

I save the returned data as localStorage and then uses this data in my pageinit like this:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#prematchdata", function() {

    var matchinfo = {};
    matchinfo = JSON.parse(localStorage["matchinfo"])

    var content = '<h2>'+matchinfo["matchname"]+'</h2>';

    $('.infoholder').html(content);

});
```

It works, although for me it seems like the last 2 steps should be done in one, but i am not sure how to do so? It seems a little bit wrong get data, save locally and then use it? Can't this be done without the **$(document).on('click', '#gotoMatch', function () {});**?

Hoping for some help and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: There must be a better title...

Comment: The `matchinfo` which you are parsing into `localStorage`.. is it a single variable or a collection of objects/array?

Comment: json: [{"mid":"23","matchname":"Stableford"}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try sending it up using a query string. When you're using `changePage`, change your code like this :

```
$(document).on('click', '#gotoMatch', function () {

    var matchid = $(this).attr("data-id");
    $.get("http://mypage.com/json/getmatchinfo.php?matchid=" + matchid, function (data) {
        paramData = data[0];
        $.mobile.changePage("prematchdata.html", {
            transition: "slide",
            changeHash: true,
            data: paramData //added this extra parameter which will pass data as a query string
        });
    }, "json");

});
```

When you're getting it back,

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#prematchdata", function() {

    var url = $.url(document.location);
    var name= url.param("matchname");

    var content = '<h2>'+ name +'</h2>';

    $('.infoholder').html(content);

});
```

Another easy way would be use a singlepage template instead of a multi page template. Then, you could just use a global variable to get and set data.

**That said, what you're doing right now is more secure than this query string method. By using this, anyone can see what you are sending over the URL. So I advise you keep using `localStorage`.** [For more info on this, look into this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15840611/jquery-mobile-get-data-passed-to-page-via-changepage)